# Migrating .Net Framework windows service to Azure PaaS

Tags: azure, docker, windows-services, azure-webjobs, azure-worker-roles

Having being unsuccessful to find a decent resource I am finally asking it over here. I have a legacy .Net Frmework Windows Service (which is now migrated to .Net Framework 4.7.2) which I want to eventually migrate to Azure PaaS. After looking around I found 3 ways I could do that and not counting the options like hiding it behind a web app hosted in IIS because I do not think that is the correct solution. I think the correct ways are:

1) Use Worker Role: This is provided by the legacy  Cloud Services platform and due to its slow deployments and staging costs is out of question.

2) Use Web Jobs: It may need code changes but I am unable to find a decent article or tutorial in the context of windows services.

3) Use Containers: This seems to be the solution most suitable but I want some expert to guide me through it as I am completely new to docker and azure. Since the service is in .Net Framework, the target OS could only be Windows Server Core(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modernize-with-azure-and-containers/modernize-existing-apps-to-cloud-optimized/deploy-existing-net-apps-as-windows-containers) but when I pull the image I get the message that it "cannot be used on this platform". I am using Windows 10. Does this mean that I need to be working on Windows server family OS to be able to pull image which effectively means that to be able to deploy .Net Framework application in an Azure container, I need to be working on Windows Server OS.

Links to a few good reads or videos are welcome as I am unable to find may be because I am not searching it correctly. I would imagine that windows service migration to Azure is a common scenario but I may be wrong.

Comment: Can you please clarify, that you have enabled windows container from add remove windows features and your docker desktop is running with Windows container (you get this option asked during installation time of the same). Thanks

Comment: the answer is true to both. I have successfully pulled microsoft/dotnet image so that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: Do check out this link https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopModernizing/wiki/02.-How-to-containerize-the-.NET-Framework-web-apps-with-Windows-Containers-and-Docker

Comment: I am not getting the option Add => Docker Support. Docker for Windows is up and running and Visual Studio Installer confirms that Web & Cloud => Azure development is checked which provides docker support. When I go and create a .Net Core API I see the option to enable docker support or right click => docker support. I've uninstalled & reinstaled Docker => switched to Windows container and repaired Visual Studio 2017 but all that doesn't help and I am still unable to see the option which the article says I should

Answer (score 0):

Do follow the steps mentioned here 
,
https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopModernizing/wiki/02.-How-to-containerize-the-.NET-Framework-web-apps-with-Windows-Containers-and-Docker

Also for your windows service, you do have a couple of other options as well

1) Convert your app into an Azure Function and run it on timer trigger. But your app must complete execution within 5 minutes.

2) Deploy your app as a timer triggered web job.